# AngularJS Directive using TypeScript to format input field

Tags: angularjs, typescript, directive

I'm new to using angular and I'm having a hard time with writing directives. In particular I wish to write one that displays floats as percentage in the view. I would like the behaviour to be as follow: When the view loads and data is being read from the controller I want the directive to display the corresponding float-property as percentage (i.e. 0.25 -> 25%). When the user inputs an integer into the input-field I'd like it to be shown as percentage on the blur-event (i.e. 10 -> 10%). Here's my code so far:

```
restrict = "A";
require = "ngModel";
scope = {
    ngModel: "="
}

constructor( /* list of dependencies */) {

}

link = (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes, ngModel: ng.INgModelController /*ctrl: any*/): void => {
    // handle linking requirements (?)   
    element.on("onload", (): void => {
        var modelValue = ngModel.$modelValue;
        var viewValue = this.toViewValue(modelValue);
        ngModel.$setViewValue(viewValue);
        ngModel.$render();
    });
    element.on("blur", (): void => { // lambda to handle this-scope
        var viewValue = ngModel.$viewValue;
        viewValue = this.toViewValue(viewValue);
        ngModel.$setViewValue(viewValue);
        ngModel.$render();       
    });
}

private toModelValue(val: string): number {
    return 0;
}

private toViewValue(val: string): string {
    var str = val.replace("%","").trim();

    if (this.isInteger(str)) {
        var i = parseInt(str);
        if (i >= 100) {
            str = "100";
        } 
    } else if (this.isFloat(str)) {
        var f = parseFloat(str);
        str = (f * 100).toString();
    }
    return str + "%";
}

private isInteger(val: any): boolean {
    return val.match(/^[0-9]{1,3}$/);            
}

private isFloat(val: any): boolean {      
    return val.match(/^\d(\.\d{1,2})?$/);
}
```

Here's the input-field I'm applying my directive to:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="payment-interest-rate" class="col-sm-4 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-percent id="payment-interest-rate" name="paymentInterestRate" data-ng-model="ctrl.economicInfo.paymentInterestRate"
               data-ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}">
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's how I register it with my module:

```
.directive("percent", MyApp.Core.Directives.DisplayPercentageDirective.create)
```

As you cansee I'm using TypeScript and I'm having a bit of difficulty in finding relevant examples because of this. I'm using what I believe is refered to as a Directive Factory pattern(?) The blur-event works without problem however I'm struggling to trigger the directive when the template first loads. What am I doing wrong?

Regards Kristofer

Comment: Can you show us the HTML where you're using the directive?

Comment: Updated my Q. Thank you for taking time to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use the blur and onload functionality. Angular got $formatters and $parsers for that. Look at the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

With a formatter you can format the model value to a certain display text that will be used in the DOM. And with a parser you can parse the DOM's value so that your entered percentage will be a float in your model.

Update your link method, to something like this:

```
ngModel.$formatters.push(toViewValue);
ngModel.$parsers.push(toModelValue);
```